# SQL changing date format 200901 to jan09

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i'm having this issue at the moment where i find it difficult to convert the date format from my access to match the date format on my dscp
on my access the date format is 200901 which is the year 2009 and the month 01 on my dscp apps the format is jan-09 
how do i change the date from access to match the date on my dscp via sql 
any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following query you can get your expected date format:

```
DECLARE @Moment AS VARCHAR (6) = '200901';
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), CAST(@Moment + '01' AS DATETIME), 100) + '-' + 
       RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(@Moment + '01' AS DATETIME), 1), 2);
-- OUTPUT Jan-09
```

Comment: I'm completely lost in here should i do first 
select * From tbl name where date = jan-09
At What point do i add this Query

where do i add the DECLARE @Moment AS VARCHAR (6) = '200901';
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), CAST(@Moment + '01' AS DATETIME), 100) + '-' + 
       RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(@Moment + '01' AS DATETIME), 1), 2);

Thanks in advance